# How to read DTEX file format in Nuke?

Tags: xml, bash, nuke, renderman

I'd like to add Pixar RenderManProServer 21.5 library's components for The Foundry Nuke on a Mac. These components are crucial for reading in `DTEX` format (for deep compositing). Foundry's User Guide tells me that I need to create an XML **environment.plist** file and place it in **.MacOSX** directory.

[You can see it here.](https://help.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/8.0/content/user_guide/configuring_nuke/setting_environment_variables.html)

But it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH</key> 
        <string>/Applications/Pixar/RenderManProServer-21.5/lib</string> 
        <key>RMANTREE</key>
        <string>/Applications/Pixar/RenderManProServer-21.5</string> 
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Is there any other way to install RenderMan library's components for Nuke on a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` is no longer supported in macOS (since 10.8). So, you need to put some lines in a hidden file `~/.bash_profile` using `pico` editor.

In `Terminal` execute a `sudo` command:

```
sudo pico .bash_profile

# you need an administrator password for sudo command
```

and then put these lines in `.bash_profile` file:

```
echo RenderManProServer environment variables are set...
export NUKE_TEMP_DIR=/var/tmp/nuke-u501/
export NUKE_PATH=/Users/swift/.nuke
export RMANTREE=/Applications/Pixar/RenderManProServer-21.5/
export RMSTREE=/Applications/Pixar/RenderManProServer-21.5/
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Pixar/RenderManProServer-21.5/lib/
export RMANFB=it
export PATH=$PATH:$RMANTREE/bin:$RMSTREE/bin/it.app/Contents/MacOS:$RMSTREE/bin/slim.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Do not forget to save this file pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and exit `pico` editor pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.